owrt - preprocess the package source files
I'm dealing with an OWRT project containing a custom package.
My need is to get the preprocessed files of the package's source code files instead of the compiled ones. I read the overriding build options guide but in this way I can add extra compilation options without changing the compilation directive from '-c' to '-E' (required to avoid gcc to go over the preprocessing step).
Is there an easy way to change the compiler directive?
